# How do you take values from multiple row from a JTable and assign it to a variable?

Tags: java, sqlite, swing, jtable

I have a table(1 column, multiple rows) containing a list of Book names and a button.
What is the right selection listener so that if I select MULTIPLE rows on the table, it will assign the values of the selected rows into a variable in concatenated format when I press the button?

example, if I select Item 1 through 7 from the table, it will be assigned to the variable as:

```
String selectedBooks = item1 + item2 + item3...;
```

i will use the values of the `selectedBooks` for a sqlite query later.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `table.getSelectedRows()` will return the indices of selected rows. Then you use `table.getValueAt(row,column)` method to get the value from a specific cell.

A tiny example:

```
public class SelectedRowExample extends JFrame {
    public SelectedRowExample() {
        super("");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("Column");
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Hello" });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Stack" });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { "Overflow" });
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e -> {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int row : table.getSelectedRows()) {
                    sb.append(table.getValueAt(row, 0));
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(table);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SelectedRowExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Selecting "Hello" prints: `Hello`

Selecting "Hello" & "World" prints: `HelloWorld`

Selecting all rows prints: `HelloStackOverflow`

Comment: this works, however I need to have commas ',' in between every value because I will use it for an sqlite query. Is that posible here?

Comment: I'm leaning towards using `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`, but I don't know how to assign the selected values into a variable. I'm new to java programming.

Comment: @itskenleton See 
[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
. Using `sb.append(",");` will do what you want.